# Ruby Rails multiple virtual attribute single database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, attributes, virtual

Writing a ROR application in which a single database field (longitude) is to be displayed as multiple screen fields (long_degrees, long_minutes, long_seconds, long_direction).  I am currently attempting to add edits to the model without scuccees.

I am using the gem geo_position to store both longitude and latitude.

The specific error I am get is that I can't access the screen fields in the Model.  In the code I display below  will show (commented out as causing errors) how I have attempted to access the fields in the Model.  I have tried all sorts of IF statements without success.

MVC

1- Model - Drills

```
    class Drill < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
    ...
    validate :validate_longitude

    def validate_longitude
       # if self.long.degrees > 180
       # if long.degrees > 180
       # if 
       #   line above causes error
       #   errors.add(self.lat.degrees, "Degrees must be between 0 and 180")
       # end
    end
```

Using the first line "If test test I get the following error
        undefined method `long' for #

2- Views - _form

```
    ....
    <%= "Longitude - degrees " %>
    <% if @drill.longitude%>
      <%= f.fields_for :long do |m| %>
        <%= m.input_field :degrees, as: :integer, value: longitude(@drill).degrees %>
        <%= "minutes "%>
        <%= m.input_field :minutes, as: :integer, value: longitude(@drill).minutes %>
        <%= "seconds "%>
        <%= m.input_field :seconds, as: :decimal, value: longitude(@drill).seconds %>
        <%= "direction "%>
        <%= m.input_field :direction, collection: %w{W E}, as: :select, selected: longitude(@drill).direction, include_blank: false %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.fields_for :long do |m| %>
      <%= m.input_field :degrees, as: :integer, value: '' %>
      <%= "minutes "%>
      <%= m.input_field :minutes, as: :integer, value: '' %>
      <%= "seconds "%>
      <%= m.input_field :seconds, as: :decimal, value: '' %>
      <%= "direction "%>
      <%= m.input_field :direction, collection: %w{W E}, as: :select, include_blank: false %>
    <% end %>
```

In the Controller
        class DrillsController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :load_drill, except: [:index, :new, :create]

```
   def index
     @drills = Drill.all
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @drills }
    end
  end

  ...
  private

    def drill_params
    params.require(:drill).permit(:name, :country_id,:state_id, :basin_id, 
          :directional_offset_metres, :ground_level_elevation_metres,
          :rotary_table_elevation_metres, :lat, :long, :sub_basin_structure_ids=>[]  )
    end
    ...
```

many thanks
Pierre

The database virtual attribute is name long (one also for lat) and the database column is called longitude.
Database column stored as longitude = "19 deg 19' 19.19" W" 
and displayed as 
Longitude - degrees 19    minutes 19     seconds 19.19   direction W

Comment: is long the name of the database column?

Comment: Hi Manoj, new to stack overflow. The database virtual attribute is name long (one also for lat) and the database column is called longitude. Database column stored as longitude = "19 deg 19' 19.19" W" and displayed as Longitude - degrees 19 minutes 19 seconds 19.19 direction W

Comment: How are you setting the data in the longitude attribute field from long virtual attribute? Can you paste in the code in the model. Also the post params which is causing the issue.

Comment: Setting the longitude attribute data as oer the view.  I have included gem geo_position which parses longitude into degrees, minutes, seconds, and direction.

Comment: Previoulsy was converting longitude degress, minutes, seconds, and direction using the geo_position gem specifically GeoPosition::Conversion::Dms.new and cathcing errors in the controller.  I am trying to change the code so that I check the longitude degreees, minutes, seconds, and direction before calling GeoPosition::Coversion so that I hande errors better.  This is where I am stuck.  I can't seem to access the lond degrees screen field in the model.

Comment: No I am talking about the model. When the user submits the form, how is the value in long assigned to the longitude attribute?

Comment: why dont you want to use serializing?

Comment: hanks all.  Hi manoj.  I think your qquestion about where in in model value is being assigned is where I am having the error.  Specifically as above for the view.  In the model I try to validate what the user has typed in with: validate :check_longitude and then in (check_longiude) def check_longitude I am unable to access the screen fields.  I try if self.long.degrees > 180 as well amoungst meny others but no luck. Thanks - Pierre